# sql on mysql about join

Tags: mysql

the code below provide a result too much Infact i want to list the customer that never buy somethink How can i fix the code below

```
SELECT
webboard.listweb.id,
webboard.listweb.iditempro,
webboard.listweb.url,
webboard.listweb.useradddate,
webboard.listweb.expiredate,
webboard.prorecord.urlpostonweb
webboard.prorecord.urlpostonweb
FROM
webboard.listweb ,
webboard.prorecord

Where listweb.id Not In 
             (select webboard.prorecord.idlist From webboard.prorecord )
```

Comment: @tee - You should accept some answers to your previous questions. You are doing a cartesian join on `webboard.listweb , webboard.prorecord` I have no idea how to fix it as I don't really understand what you are trying to do here. Why is `webboard.prorecord.urlpostonweb` in the `select` list if you are lookling for records without matching entries in `webboard.prorecord`? And what is `idlist`? I'm hoping this isn't some comma delimited list of `ids`? Please provide example data and desired results.

Comment: As Matrin says, you should accept more answers to your previous questions if you would like more help. Click on the "tick" next to the best answer in each of your questions with answers.

Comment: I am not sure i understand correct or not when i try to give score it ask for user name and password I think I sign in already it show my name

Comment: @tee: This is from the FAQ: When you have decided which answer is the most helpful to you, mark it as the accepted answer by clicking on the check box outline to the left of the answer. This lets other people know that you have received a good answer to your question. Doing this is helpful because it shows other people that you’re getting value from the community. (If you don’t do this, people will often politely ask you to go back and accept answers for more of your questions!)

Comment: i can not explain in english so I just make something similar such as I have a customer table and sale table I want to list some customer that never buy goods but mycode it list a duplicate customer name how can I fix it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the syntax

```
FROM
webboard.listweb ,
webboard.prorecord
```

will perform a cartesian, or cross, join on the tables involved. So for every row in the table `listweb` all the rows in `prorecord` are displayed.

You need to use an `INNER JOIN` to only select the rows in `listweb` that have related rows in the `prorecord` table. What are the fields which identify the rows (your Primary Keys) and what is the name of the foreign key field in the `prorecord` table?

**EDIT:** Just re-read the question and comments and I see you want the rows in `listweb` which *do not* have an entry in `prorecord`

Your `SELECT` will then look like:

```
SELECT
  webboard.listweb.id,
  webboard.listweb.iditempro,
  webboard.listweb.url,
  webboard.listweb.useradddate,
  webboard.listweb.expiredate,
  webboard.prorecord.urlpostonweb
  -- webboard.prorecord.urlpostonweb -- You have this field twice
FROM webboard.listweb LEFT JOIN webboard.prorecord
    ON webboard.listweb.id = webboard.prorecord.idlist -- I'm guessing at the foreign key here
WHERE webboard.prorecord.idlist IS NULL
```